# Archimedes Ship Mod for Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

Ok I am wondering does the Archimedes Ship mod allow for a say a Air Ship that's not in water to still move, by not in water I mean in the air. So i if you could please let me know that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Archimedes Ship mod's layout is only for boats and hot air balloons. Hot Air Balloons can be made with all the materials of a ship but require a balloon (a wool with 1 string under it).

Here is the [wiki](http://www.minecraftmods.com/archimedes-ships/) for full mod details.